# targeting small devices with mediaelements

Tags: css, html, video, responsive-design, mediaelement.js

I'm playing around with mediaelement.js

very good so far

I just face a little problem when I target small devices, the video is not automatically resized to the new device size

I suspect the #containingBlock to be problematic, so I tried to target it with media query

I have tried Chris Coyer suggestion for responsive video
[responsive video tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php)
but it screws what mediaelement.js outpout

maybe someone have an idea on how I can issue for iphone likes

my page is available at [my page](http://med-innovation.com)

I use the following html to embed my videos

```
<div id="containingBlock">
        <video id="introVid" poster="http://med-innovation.com/wp-content/themes/med/images/video_start.png" controls="control" preload="none">     
            <source src="http://med-innovation.com/wp-content/themes/med/media/ElevatorPitch.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            <source src="http://med-innovation.com/wp-content/themes/med/media/ElevatorPitch.webm" type="video/webm" />
            <source src="http://med-innovation.com/wp-content/themes/med/media/ElevatorPitch.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://med-innovation.com/wp-content/themes/med/build/flashmediaelement.swf">
                <param name="movie" value="http://med-innovation.com/wp-content/themes/med/build/flashmediaelement.swf" />
                <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&amp;file=http://med-innovation.com/wp-content/themes/med/media/ElevatorPitch.mp4" />
                <img src="http://med-innovation.com/wp-content/themes/med/images/fail.jpg" width="640" height="360" title="Il n'est pas possible de visionner une video avec votre navigateur" />
            </object>
        </video>    
        <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) 
        {
            // declare object for video
            var player = new MediaElementPlayer('#introVid', 
            {
             // if the <video width> is not specified, this is the default
                defaultVideoWidth: 640,
                // if the <video height> is not specified, this is the default
                defaultVideoHeight: 360,
                // if set, overrides <video width>
                videoWidth: -1,
                // if set, overrides <video height>
                videoHeight: -1,
                // enables Flash and Silverlight to resize to content size
                enableAutosize: true,
                // the order of controls you want on the control bar (and other plugins below)
                features: ['playpause','loop','current','progress','duration','volume'],
                success: function (mediaElement, domObject) 
                { 
                    // add event listener
                    mediaElement.addEventListener('ended', function(e) 
                    {
                           window.location = "http://med-innovation.com/choice/";
                    }, false);
                }
            });
        });

        </script>
```

and on the css I have

```
video {width: 100%    !important; height: auto   !important;}

#containingBlock {
width: 640px;
height: 360px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align:center;
}

@media(max-width: 520px)
{
#page-wrap, #colophon {width: auto; margin: 7px auto; }
#containingBlock {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, any idea for me problem

Comment: maybe this work http://webtonio.com/40/ and add tags like html5,css to the question

Comment: Please make a fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/ so we can debug the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

i know you mentioned Chris Coyier and that tutorial, but check out this plug in by the same person specifically for video responsiveness.

http://fitvidsjs.com/

good luck